# How do foci of an ellipse work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

How can an ellipse even be defined by two points and a set of all points whose **sum of distances to these two points(foci) equals some constant value**(which then turns out to be 2 major radii)?

Comment: Refer to [Ellipses In Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#In_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: Well, just like that.

Comment: You may want to watch an [ellipsograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trammel_of_Archimedes) at work.

Comment: @Gonçalo Maybe it's an intuitive and extremely obvious definition, but not for me. I just don't understand why this set of rules eventually gives an ellipse

Comment: @MathBun How about this as an intuitive thought: tie a string between two points that are on a horizontal segment, longer than the distance between them. Put a pen/stylus somewhere along the string and stretch it out. The two lengths from the stylus to the two points add up, but wherever you move it, there's some "backtrack" to it. If the stylus is equidistant from the points, above the line between them, the backtracking is the distance up and down. But with the stylus on the far side of one of the points, more backtracking is needed, as the string redoubles on itself.

Comment: @Gonçalo I see it as a stretched circle($(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1$)

Comment: OK, do you understand why this set of rules gives _anything at all_?

Comment: Hence when the string is near one of the two points (the foci), it's a shorter distance from the closest focus--the "skinny end" of the ellipse, if you will. Nearer the middle, it can swing out a bit farther from the foci, but it still has to keep closer to the center.

Comment: So if you have the foci at $(\pm c,0)$ and the length of the string $d$, you can say $\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=d$.  You now want to remove the square roots and drop any spurious  solutions so you end up with a result which looks like  $\frac{x^2}{\text{something}^2} + \frac{y^2}{\text{something else}^2} =1$.  What have you tried?

Comment: The technical term is "semi-major axis". This video shows the relationship well, with the sum (the major axis) below the ellipse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLjnTgXXgXk

Comment: An ellipse can be defined in several different ways: - as the section of a cone - as the locus of points with fixed sum of distances from the foci - as the locus of points with fixed ratio of distances from focus and directrix - as a stretched circle. Given a definition, the other properties can be proved as theorems. If you are interested in any of those proofs, you should ask a more specific question.